# Retrieving a GoogleDoc via API and generate a PDF replacing with own text

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf-generation, google-docs-api

I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve a simple **GoogleDoc** (via *gdata python client*) and render a PDF replacing some custom #[PLACE_HOLDERS] with my own information.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#SearchingDocs and look for Downloading documents. That should get you started.

Comment: I edited your revision cause this is really on GAE

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the startup :D

Comment: My doubt is how to retrive the inner content of the document. The download() method of gdata docservice needs a file_path, and in AppEngine we can only have blobs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I've looking for. The problem was that I tried to use **DocsService** (v1 API) instead of **DocsClient** (v2).

**WARNING**: The examples of gdata/OAuth in *AppEngine* **are outdated** - http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/oauth/oauth_on_appengine/main_hmac.py.

To get an **updated version** check this link (It's for *Django*, but you only have to change the *request/response*) - http://pamelafox-samplecode.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsimporter/importer/views.py

So after changing the Oauth method to a newer version, I managed to get the file contents in HTML,DOC,PDF, TXT, etc. Just change the exportFormat.

For the future, if anyone needs:

```
_client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient('My-Prety-App-v1')
# Set your prefered auth method
# ...
entry = _client.GetDoc('document:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
exportFormat = 'html'
content = _client.GetFileContent(uri=entry.content.src + '&exportFormat=' + exportFormat)
self.response.out.write(content)
```